# How can I increase the thickness of lines in android plot line graph?

Tags: android, androidplot

I searched for this . but I didn't find anything useful. In the Documentation of LineAndPointFormatter class there is nothing mentioned about thickness .. Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, please explain your problem with code you used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May this help you:

```
    LineAndPointFormatter lineAndPointFormatter = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0), null, null);

    //change the line width
    Paint paint = lineAndPointFormatter.getLinePaint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    lineAndPointFormatter.setLinePaint(paint);
```

Answer (score 3):

The paint object is mutable so you don't need to make a copy of it to set it.

```
LineAndPointFormatter lineAndPointFormatter = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0), null, null);

// Set the line (stroke) width.
lineAndPointFormatter.getLinePaint().setStrokeWidth(3);
```